# Iframe Flash when playing HTML5 Video

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, video

When embedding a html5 video in an iframe on chrome (latest version) there is a white flash which fills the iframe when play is clicked.

I've noticed that if I give the iframe a background colour then this will reflect the colour of the flash.

Are there any solutions to this?

Thanks!